# Error: Could not find the correct Provider<MessageDao> above this MessageList Widget

Tags: flutter, dart

I am trying to find the problem, I even did a hot restart but its not working I'm stuck on it, Someone please look at it

The following ProviderNotFoundException was thrown building MessageList(dirty, state: MessageListState#24cda):
Error: Could not find the correct Provider above this MessageList Widget

This happens because you used a `BuildContext` that does not include the provider

Main.dart

```
  Future<void> main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  await Firebase.initializeApp();
  runApp(const App());
}

class App extends StatelessWidget {
  const App({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MultiProvider(
      providers: [
        ChangeNotifierProvider<UserDao>(
          lazy: false,
          create: (_) => UserDao(),
        ),
      ],
      child: Builder(builder: (context) {
        return MaterialApp(
          debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
          title: 'RayChat',
          theme: ThemeData(primaryColor: const Color(0xFF3D814A)),
          home: Consumer<UserDao>(builder: (context, userDao, child) {
            if (userDao.isLoggedIn()) {
              return const MessageList();
            } else {
              return const Login();
            }
          }),
        );
      }),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I found that I was missing the provider for messagedao so I added a provider under UserDao

```
Provider<MessageDao>(
  create: (_) => MessageDao(),
  lazy: false,
)
```